# Some conflicts were found in the installation area.(Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, installation, plugins, android-gradle-plugin, conflict

I'm currently using Android Studio 4.0.1 and I've been trying to update it to the latest version that was recently released(4.0.2) but each time I click the update button, it displays the below error:

"Some conflicts were found in the installation area."

"Some of the conflicts below do not have a solution, so the patch cannot be applied."
"Press 'Cancel' to exit."

I have searched all the similar related issues on this site, some had similar issues with me but it didn't solve the error because the missing file it indicated has something to do with plugins and most people's own were different

##### A Screenshot of it:

[image]

I would like to know if there's anywhere I can get all the required latest plugins for Android studio because I previously uninstalled Android Studio, so maybe I wiped out the plugin files in the process. My current Android Gradle Plugin version is 4.0.1, then the Gradle version is 6.1.1.

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder where the studio is trying to install to may be the issue, You can always try to uninstall Android Studio and then install the version you wish to install.

Comment: Ok,what will I lose if I uninstall? Because I don't want to lose my important files

Comment: You won't loose any of your project files if that's what your worried about. So if you've been working on an app you won't loose any data, as it's stored in a different location and not on the Program Files. In my experience you don't loose much. I haven't even lost the libraries when I've manually uninstalled and then reinstalled .

Comment: No worries, go ahead and hit the "^" arrow if the answer was useful to you.

Comment: Sure, just did that